# Get count from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a many-to-many, `HMT` model setup and I want to add a count value to return as part of my `tab_community#index` method. The models for the table of interest and the join table are as follows:

```
class TabCommunity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ref_community_type

  has_many :tab_client_project_communities
  has_many :tab_projects, through: :tab_client_project_communities

  has_many :tab_community_accounts
  has_many :tab_accounts, through: :tab_community_accounts

  has_many :tab_client_project_communities
  has_many :ref_platforms, through: :tab_client_project_communities
end

class TabCommunityAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tab_community
  belongs_to :tab_account
end
```

The `#index` method currently looks like this:

```
_tab_community_ids = params[:tab_community_ids].split(',')
@tab_communities = TabCommunity.where(id: _tab_community_ids).includes(:ref_platforms).all.order(:updated_at).reverse_order
```

This query is what I want to replicate in ActiveRecord:

```
select (select count(*) from tab_community_accounts where tab_community_id = c.id) as cnt, c.* from tab_communities c
```

The results I want are below:

```
7318    149 sports_writers  7   2017-12-17 15:45:36.946965  2017-12-17 15:45:36.946965
0   172 random_admin    8   2018-04-16 19:21:21.844041  2018-04-16 19:21:21.844041
2731    173 random_aacc 7   2018-04-16 19:22:35.074461  2018-04-16 19:22:35.074461
```

(The 1st column is `count(*) from tab_community_accounts`, the rest is from `tab_communities`.)

From what I've seen so far I should use either `.select()` or `.pluck()` but neither one works for me. I tried this out:

```
TabCommunity.pluck("distinct tab_community_accounts.tab_account_id as cnt").where(id: _tab_community_ids).includes(:ref_platforms).all.order(:updated_at).reverse_order
```

Is this close to what I need or am I completely off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is something like:

```
@tab_communities = TabCommunity
  .where(id: _tab_community_ids)
  .select('tab_communities.*, count(tab_community_accounts.id) AS cnt')
  .left_outer_joins(:tab_community_accounts)
  .includes(:ref_platforms) # consider if you actually need this
  .group(:id)
  .order(updated_at: :desc) # use an explicit order instead!
```

---

```
  TabCommunity Load (1.1ms)  SELECT tab_communities.*, count(tab_community_accounts.id) AS cnt FROM "tab_communities" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tab_community_accounts" ON "tab_community_accounts"."tab_community_id" = "tab_communities"."id" WHERE "tab_communities"."id" = 1 GROUP BY "tab_communities"."id" ORDER BY "tab_communities"."updated_at" DESC
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<TabCommunity id: 1, created_at: "2018-05-07 21:13:24", updated_at: "2018-05-07 21:13:24">]>
```

`.select` just alters the `SELECT` portion of the query. The result returned is still an `ActiveRecord::Relation` containing model instances.

ActiveRecord will automatically create an attribute for `cnt`:

```
irb(main):047:0> @tab_communities.map(&:cnt)
=> [1]
```

`.pluck` on the other hand just pulls the column values and returns an array or array of arrays if the query contains multiple columns.

```
@tab_communities = TabCommunity
  .where(id: _tab_community_ids)
  .left_outer_joins(:tab_community_accounts)
  .includes(:ref_platforms) # consider if you actually need this
  .group(:id)
  .order(updated_at: :desc)
  .pluck('tab_communities.id, count(tab_community_accounts.id) AS cnt')
```

---

```
 (1.0ms)  SELECT tab_communities.id, count(tab_community_accounts.id) AS cnt FROM "tab_communities" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tab_community_accounts" ON "tab_community_accounts"."tab_community_id" = "tab_communities"."id" WHERE "tab_communities"."id" = 1 GROUP BY "tab_communities"."id" ORDER BY "tab_communities"."updated_at" DESC
=> [[1, 1]]
```

Using `.*` with pluck is not a good idea since you don't know what order the attributes have in the resulting array.

Comment: `.left_outer_joins`  was introduced in Rails 5. See https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html for workarounds for legacy apps.